# Chrome compute CSS different on two pc

Tags: css, google-chrome

I got a very annoying problem. When I let my computer with Chrome 78.0.3904.108 compute the CSS, I got a height of **12.8** for my table. On the client pc also with Chrome 78.0.3904.108, I got with the same CSS a hight for my table row of **14**. Does anyone know which impacts this height indirectly? I use no zoom and tested both in the incognito window. Also, Firefox calculates the height on both computers to **14**. [image]

Comment: Maybe you have some CSS rule using "%" , "vh" or "vw"

Comment: which css reset did you you use?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It was the windows zoom...

[image: Windows Scale]